# Same Query - Different Azure SQL - Close Logical Reads - Different Performance

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, query-optimization

X Azure SQL DB and Y Azure SQL DB run on different SQL Elastic Pools.

Even though the same query returns different number of rows, the number of logical reads it performs are close to each other, while it takes 904ms in X Azure SQL DB, it takes 4207ms in Y Azure SQL DB.

You can find the detailed screenshot below.

[image]

How can I find the root cause for this performance difference?

Thank you very much in advance.

**--
Same query Time & IO Stats are below.**

```
-- X AZURE SQL DB QUERY TIME/IO STATS
(300 rows affected)
Table 'A'. Scan count 1, logical reads 15709, physical reads 0
Table 'B'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1488, physical reads 0
Table 'C'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0
Table 'D'. Scan count 304, logical reads 645, physical reads 0
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0
Table 'E'. Scan count 1, logical reads 603, physical reads 0
Table 'F'. Scan count 0, logical reads 1204, physical reads 0
Table 'G'. Scan count 301, logical reads 1825, physical reads 0
Table 'H'. Scan count 0, logical reads 606, physical reads 0
Table 'I'. Scan count 303, logical reads 610, physical reads 0
Table 'J'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0
Table 'K'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 906 ms,  elapsed time = 904 ms.


-- Y AZURE SQL DB QUERY TIME/IO STATS
(2 rows affected)
Table 'A'. Scan count 1, logical reads 23625, physical reads 0
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0
Table 'E'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5, physical reads 0
Table 'F'. Scan count 0, logical reads 8, physical reads 0
Table 'G'. Scan count 2, logical reads 12, physical reads 0
Table 'H'. Scan count 0, logical reads 14, physical reads 0
Table 'D'. Scan count 7, logical reads 14, physical reads 0
Table 'I'. Scan count 7, logical reads 14, physical reads 0
Table 'B'. Scan count 5, logical reads 1464, physical reads 0
Table 'C'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0
Table 'J'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0
Table 'K'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 4203 ms,  elapsed time = 4207 ms.
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be related to [parameter sniffing](https://eitanblumin.com/2022/08/25/too-many-plans-for-the-same-query-hash/). With some specific parameters the query generates a different query plan and sometimes those query plans have different performance results. The following query will return you all query plans for the same query hash:

```
SELECT TOP (10)
ClearPlanHandleFromCacheCmd = N'DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), qs.plan_handle, 1) + N');'
, qplan.query_plan, qs.query_plan_hash, txt.text, qs.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) AS qplan
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS txt
WHERE qs.query_hash = 0x150517EA5F3979B4
ORDER BY qs.execution_count DESC
```

Please change the query hash number for the query hast shown on the images you shared. On the result of the query make a click on the query plans and you may be able to see they have different operators and decisions taken by query optimizer.

Does using [OPTION(RECOMPILE)](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/using-the-option-recompile-option-for-a-statement/) provides a better performance on the query? It may help create a better plan for different parameters.

Comment: Hi @Alberto Morillo. Thank you for answer. I am running same query with literal values with OPTION(RECOMPILE) and getting bad performance on Y Azure SQL DB. I don't have parameter sniffing issue but as you said execution plans are different on X and Y Azure SQL DB. I compared all indexes and noticed that there are extra 4 indexes in Y Azure SQL DB and two of them are used in execution plan. Please note that we are using Auto-Create Index option in Azure. So my next action plan is to drop extra indexes in Y Azure SQL DB and to see same execution plan in X Azure SQL DB.

Comment: The auto-create index option most of the time it creates duplicates indexes. I do not recommend Automatic Tuning. Try to update statistics also.

Comment: I will drop auto-created indexes and update table stats which are used in the SQL for Y Azure SQL DB. Then I should see same execution plan in Y Azure SQL DB like X Azure SQL DB, right? I mean QueryPlanHash values also should be same for both DB like QueryHash values.

Comment: Add variables and assigned the literal to variables, then use the variables on the querr, this may help.